# Does 301 redirect in htaccess have to use full path?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

When changing file or directory names or "prettifying" URLs via .htaccess, I have always previously used this format:

```
Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm /newfile
```

However, according to [this](http://www.bruceclay.com/blog/how-to-properly-implement-a-301-redirect/) article, I have been doing it incorrectly all these years:

> The last section is the full path to the new file. This is a
>   fully-qualified URL, meaning you need the http://
>   (http://www.domain.com/new-file.html).

Are they correct?  I always use a redirect check script after writing my rules, and they always check out, even with relative paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truth can be found in [official docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), that says

> The new URL should be an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and hostname. In Apache HTTP Server 2.2.6 and later, a URL-path beginning with a slash may also be used, in which case the scheme and hostname of the current server will be added.

Comment: Thanks!  Was worried there a little bit. :)